# binding radio buttons with angularjs and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, data-binding

I'm trying to display the name of the respective units in: "Total displacement in". Instead of displaying "Total displacement in 1", it should display "Total displacement in pixels", instead of "Total displacement in 10" it should display  "Total displacement in centimeters" and so on dynamically, and without messing up the current values and bindings? i only want to change it in that place not in the text boxes. Im already using the ng-model and ng-value in the radio buttons, and if i change the ng-value in the radio buttons it would mess up the text box next to the slider and the one at the bottom, and i dont want that. is there any way to achieve that ?

```js
"use strict";
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
var createSlider = function(locID) {
  var elm = document.getElementById(locID);
  elm.innerHTML += "Scale : <input type='range' min=\"1\" max='50' ng-model=\"mLeftModel\">";
  elm.innerHTML += "<input type='text' ng-model=\"mLeftModel\" size='1'>";
};
createSlider("idLeft");
app.controller("exCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.mLeftModel = "1";
  $scope.units = [{
    model: "Pixels",
    number: 1
  }, {
    model: "Millimeters",
    number: 5
  }, {
    model: "Centimeters",
    number: 10
  }, {
    model: "Meters",
    number: 50
  }];
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="exCtrl">
  <input name='rad2' type="radio" ng-model="mLeftModel" ng-value="1">Pixels
  <input name='rad2' type="radio" ng-model="mLeftModel" ng-value="5">Millimeters
  <input name='rad2' type="radio" ng-model="mLeftModel" ng-value="10">Centimeters
  <input name='rad2' type="radio" ng-model="mLeftModel" ng-value="50">Meters
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="idLeft" style="outline: 3px solid"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <label>Total displacement in {{mLeftModel}}:
    <input type="text" ng-model="mLeftModel">
  </label>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, 
`Total displacement in {{(units | filter: {'number': mLeftModel})[0]['model'] }}`

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-repeat directive to get multiple radio buttons.

```
<input ng-repeat="unit in units" name='rad2' type="radio" ng-model="mLeftModel" ng-value="unit"> {{unit.model}}
```

To display the label use:

```
<label>Total displacement in {{mLeftModel.model}}:    {{mLeftModel.number}} </label>
```